# Windows upgrade on a domain joined machine

Tags: windows, domain, active-directory

Say I have a machine running Vista Business edition and I want to in-place upgrade it to Windows 7 Pro (wich is a supported upgrade path), will that machine still be domain-joined after the upgrade or do I need to re-join the domain again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the windows 7 upgrade leaves the machine joined to the domain, and it works fine after the upgrade, i've had many of these. However there have been some occurrences where I have had issues with domain connectivity, not being able to contact a DC or browse the network properly. Dis-Joining and re-joining the domain has solved this.